# Hard Drive Error on Dell PowerEdge T710: Replacing Faulty Drive in Slot 5

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I own a Dell PowerEdge T710 server, and recently I encountered an issue where the display screen displayed an orange screen with the error message "e1810 hard drive 5 fault. review & clear sel."

Is that mean the hard drive installed in slot 5 needs to be replaced?
Just shut down the computer and replace it with a new one?

Is there a way to determine the storage capacity of my computer's hard drive in slot 5 without physically removing the hard drive?
[image]

I checked my computer. It shows only 1 harddisk.

[image]

Comment: That looks like diskpart shows two disks to me? I'm guessing they are both virtual RAID devices though; do you have the Dell "Server Administrator" (OMSA) software installed, or at least MegaCLI?

Comment: @u1686_grawity My server doesn't have OMSA software installed. Anyway to check? How this error is virtual RAID error but physical harddrive no error?